# New Ubuntu/Linux user have some questions

Tags: windows, kernel, deb

I'm a new Linux/Ubuntu user came from Windows environment trying to figure my way into Linux and planning to make a full transition when i feel ready, and have some basic questions to make things clear to me.

1- Im using Ubuntu 13.04 with Kernel 3.8 pre-installed, what changes would happen if i installed newer kernel? will i lose my installed apps? drivers? theme? configurations? anything i should be aware of in this matter?

2- I install most of my apps directly from repositories/ppa's , if i installed apps downloaded from sites - .deb files - will i be able to get lastest updates to these apps? or would i update them manually?

3- Is there any IDM like or any download manager that is integrated with Browsers, to click and download with some nice features - multithreading, schedule, resume?

As i mentioned above i just came from Windows, any tips to make things easier and clear would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: These comments are separate topics; you should ask them in separate questions. The short answer to (2) is no, since there is no repository, there is no automatic update. (3) I have no idea, (1) merits longer answer (but search in the archives, I'm sure there is a relevant answer already there).

Comment: Please do read up on the rules for AskUbuntu. In general we would like to see 1 question so people can answer that question and we all upvote the ones that are good, and you accept the one that is your best answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, on all questions. But do not bother and stick with the one that is installed by default. We all do. Well almost all of us do. If a newer kernel becomes available (mostly from security updates) you will get an update warning and the system will take care of it.
2. Depends on the app. In general you need to manually update but sometimes it has an automated updater. Example: Aptana IDE; you install it yourself through a tar file but it does warn you and does update if you let it from within Aptana.
3. There is a list of downloadmanagers here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DownloadManager but these are mostly single browser (firefox).